# DataType JSONP is screwing up ASP.NET MVC + JQuery 1.5+ plugins?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp

I've been working with MVC 3 & JQuery 1.5.2 and I'm using some plugins like jqGrid and Token Input. I notice that with both if the datatype is set to **json** they fail (where they did work in jQuery before 1.5) since the ajax request datatype seems to interpret this as **jsonp** and the ajax call looks for a callback in line with the way jsonp works, which most of the plugins don't implement. If however I remove the datatype or change it to **text json** all the plugins work fine.

For example, the only way I could get the latest jqGrid to work was to modify the source to accept "text json" as the datatype.

I can't understand why datatype=json has been changed so that now it needs to be datatype='text json' seems like a pretty big breaking change to me?

Has anyone got any idea or what's going on or workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problems and, after too much googling, I ended up it was because of the jquery.validate.min.js, that forced jsonp calls.

No more problems with the new version of JQuery Validation 1.8

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read this article

[jQuery 1.5 broke my JSONP request, and its my own damn fault.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/177186/jQuery-1-5-broke-my-JSONP-request-and-its-my-own-d.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Nicholas that makes sense but if you use 3rd party controls what can you do. Ideally you want to avoid altering the source since the plugin will then be out of sync with future changes.